# bash no abash: /src/github.com/tomnomnom/gf/gf-completion.bash: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo

When ever I do sudo su in ubuntu i get this weird error everytime there is not any problem in using anything but I just want to ask why is it coming even tho even do i have deleted this file already why is it automatically executing bash to this file

Comment: Likely somewhere in your initialization scripts, that file is called. Run `su` with `-c bash -xl` and see if you find something.

Comment: Also try `grep -Fre gf-completion.bash /etc/ ~/.bashrc*` after `su`.

Comment: when i run grep -Fre gf-completion.bash /etc/ ~/.bashrc*  i get this  /root/.bashrc:source $GOPATH/src/github.com/tomnomnom/gf/gf-completion.bash

Comment: Comment out or delete that line.

Comment: You also might want to check this discussion: https://github.com/tomnomnom/gf/issues/28

Comment: thank you so much man i really appreciate i just removed the path from bashrc and its not happening again

Comment: You're welcome. Kindly accept accept my answer so this question becomes concluded.

Comment: from where to accept i'll accept right now

Comment: You should find a tick box on the upper left of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70613357/445221

Comment: accepted man thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an old code in his `~/.bashrc` file which was found by `grep -Fre gf-completion.bash /etc/ ~/.bashrc*`:

```
/root/.bashrc:source $GOPATH/src/github.com/tomnomnom/gf/gf-completion.bash
```